# send current date to Api using typescript in format (DateTime)

Tags: angular, date, typescript, datetime

how can I send current date to API using typescript in a specific format (DateTime) 
when I send date to API, it's sent in this format so I got the error.

my ts code:

```
date: Date;
constructor( private dataStorageService: DataStorageService) {
    this.date = new Date();
}
onSubmit(Message , form : FormGroup){
    let newMsg = {
        username: Message.username,
        header: Message.header,
        content: Message.content,
        file: Message.file
    }
  this.dataStorageService.postMessage(newMsg, this.Id , this.date).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('done');
      console.log(this.date);
      }, error => {
          console.error("Error saving jobs!");
      })
}
```

http://api.azharcouncil.com/api/notification/PostNotification?user_id=15&Header=hj&Content=hjh&File_Path=null&**date=Wed%20Nov%2015%202017%2010:44:56%20GMT+0200%20(Egypt%20Standard%20Time)**

So my request is invalid because of the date format...

Comment: You can use the date pipe of angular to convert the date in the form you want for your server to receive, check this link out https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: i dont send date form form i just want to send the current date with the message

Comment: this.dateToServer = this.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900';

now this.dataStorageService.postMessage(newMsg, this.Id , this.dateToServer).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('done');
      console.log(this.date);
      }, error => {
          console.error("Error saving jobs!");
      })

how about that? Does it make sense?

Comment: no there is error in  `date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z':'+0900';`

Comment: try this or any other pipe in the angular link that I had shared with you before new Date() | date:'full'

Comment: I have created a sample code for you please have a look in the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the complete answer to your question.

1. Import the DatePipe from in the main module and provide that to your main module in main.module.ts in your provider array like given below:

   ```
   import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';    
   providers: [DatePipe]
   ```
2. Use it in your ts file with these methods, also import DatePipe from @angular/common in your ts file as well.

   ```
   import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
   ```
3. Then in your constructor initialize this:

   ```
   constructor(private _http: HttpClient, public datepipe: DatePipe) { }
   ```
4. Now use these methods to get the correct date format:

   ```
   let myDate = new Date(); 
   console.log(this.datepipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
   someDateVar = this.datepipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
   ```
5. Now someDateVar can be used to send it to server which has the date format you need. Also note that you can use multiple other date formats as well which are given in the Angular date pipe documentation.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. Just an observation, in your example's format you are passing minutes in the place of months, the correct wold be 'yyyy-MM-dd' with capital 'M's

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by using moment.js

**Sample coding**

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone'

export enum dateFormats {
    'DMY'= 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    'MDY'= 'MM/DD/YYYY'
}

// converts datestring to date
export const ToDate = (dateString: string, format: string) => new Date(moment(dateString, format))

// converts date to datestring
export const ToDateString = (date: Date, format: string) => moment(date).format(format)
```

**Usage (in component)**

```
const dateValue = new Date() // Date = Tue Feb 19 2020 12:05:22 GMT+0530 (IST)
const dateString = ToDateString(dateValue, dateFormats.DMY) // dateString = '19/02/2020'
```